# How to share picture from Photo Gallery to my application?

Tags: android, titanium, image

I have an application written in Titanium.
 And on Android device, in Photo gallery, click share via. Picture can share via Gmail, Message, Goolge+, ...
 I want add one more option that picture can share via my application. 
 Is there have any solution for this process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an intent filter to intercept the correct `Intant.ACTION_SEND` as shown [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent):

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 </intent-filter>

 var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
     fullscreen: false,
     exitOnClose: true
 });
 win.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
     var intent = Ti.Android.currentActivity.getIntent();
     var iname = Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM;
     if (intent && intent.hasExtra(iname)) {
         // Create ImageView from TiBlob
         var blob = intent.getBlobExtra(iname);
         win.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
             image: blob,
             height: 300,
             width: 300,
             left: 0,
             top: 0
         }));
     } else {
         Ti.API.info('No extra named "' + iname + '" found in Intent');
     }
 });        
 win.open();
```

Comment: Now, It has icon when press "Share via" in Photo Gallery. But when open application, I can't catch Intent to get image.